# Why define a subclass as a friend of its own parent class?

Tags: c++

I was looking through some C++ code written by a (now departed) coworker quite a long time ago, and found an odd class definition I'm trying to decipher.

```
class BaseClass
{
    friend SubClass1;
    friend SubClass2;
}

class SubClass1 : public BaseClass
{
    ...
}

class SubClass2 : public BaseClass
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a benefit to designing a class hierarchy this way? If you want access to private methods of BaseClass from the subclasses wouldn't you just move them to protected instead of private? I feel there is an idiom I'm missing here.

Comment: The question's dual: Why not?

Comment: @trinithis: "Why not?" is easier to answer: the more unusual your code structure, the more chance there is that a reader will misunderstand its behaviour or purpose. If you can express your intended behaviour and interface with a more commonly used code structure then you should do so for the benefit of whoever next reads the code. This is subjective, but I would say that `protected` is more commonly used (and therefore easier to understand) than declaring sub-classes as friends.

Comment: @trinithis: The most obvious reason of why not to do this is that now your base-class needs to know about all its sub-classes.

Comment: @trinithis: `friend`ship is the strongest form of coupling, and coupling is generally to be kept to a minimum.

Comment: I was being facetious: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28mathematics%29

Comment: On planet C++, friends should be avoided. Like in life, they are usually more trouble than they are worth. *Is that a quote by Scott Myers or am I paraphrasing?!*

Comment: @EdHeal: Since C++ friends has access to your private parts, the are more like friends with benefits than *just* friends. And we all know that friends with benefits will lead to stronger coupling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is hard to say without looking at the real design of the library, but the two approaches are not equivalent. Using `friend` in this way provides greater access to lesser types than you can get by declaring all members `protected`.

**Greater access**

The meaning of `protected` is not exactly *grant access to all base members everywhere to the derived type*, but rather *grant access to the protected members of the base subobject inside the derived type*. The difference is that a derived type cannot access protected members or a type that is not of its own type or derived types.

Consider two versions of a class one of which has all members protected and no friend declaration, another that has all members private and declares a subclass as a friend. Now consider that the derived type had a function:

```
struct derived : base {
   void f( base& b ) {
       //std::cout << b.protected_method() << std::endl; // Error
       std::cout << protected_method() << std::endl;     // Ok, accessing your own base
   }
};
```

In the case of using `protected`, the issue there is that `protected` does not let you tweak the contents of any object other than `derived` or types derived from `derived`, but the argument could be a `base` or any other type that extends `base` and it not otherwise related to `derived`.

This restriction is a bit less clear in some other use cases, and you might be able to obtain access to those *protected* members outside of your own hierarchy, just not in a direct simple way (I consider that a bug in the access specifier specification of the language).

On the other hand, if `derived` is a friend of the `base` the above code will compile, as `derived` is granted access to every `base` instance anywhere, be it a subobject of `derived` or not.

**To lesser types**

The `protected` access specifier is transtive, once you grant access through `protected` to a derived type, you are granting it to all types that derive from it, and also to any other type that might inherit directly from you. It is impossible to control what types are granted access and which are not. On the other hand friendship is precise, only the members of the types declared as friend will have access. Friendship is not transitive, so type other than your declared friends will have access.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know of any particular idiom that involves that, but a simple answer might be that they wished to expose private members only to a few subclasses out of many. Alternatively, they may simple not have understood the concept of protected members.

Comment: This is a tough question to provide a definitive answer for so I chose this one- thanks to everyone that had some input.  In the specific case of my code there are 4 subclasses and all 4 are included as friends, but I can well imagine a situation where Datalore's answer would be a good reason to use this structure.

Comment: @whazzmaster: The fact that there are only 4 derived types in that library does not limit you from creating another 4 more (or how many you want) outside of the library, so the answer stands. The main differences of the two approaches are that the friendship approach provides greater access to lesser types than `protected`... I have added a longer explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about an idiom, but one possibility is that you have *other* subclasses.  This way, the friends would have access, but not the other subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

In the example code, there is no use of making the subclass a `friend`. As you mentioned, it's better to make the members `protected` which are required to be accessed by its subclass. Otherwise it's a **code smell**.

However, there is **one genuine case** where one has to make the subclass as `friend` of its base class. It's when you want to create a `final class` (like in Java). Here is the [example code](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#no-derivation) to explain that corner case.

Comment: There might be more than one case where it makes sense, and the use case of *sealing* (C# term) or making *final* (Java term) a type requires `virtual` inheritance, which is not used in the question. Incidentally *sealing* a class is much easier now in C++11 (i.e. you can create a generic `seal` rather than having to implement one for each type you need sealed)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, isn't `seal` a MS specific keyword. I think in C++11 there is a `final` keyword. Yes, it's with `virtual` inheritance... though it's not asked specifically by OP, I thought it's worth mentioning.

Comment: The `final` *special identifier* does not have the full *keyword* grade (i.e. it is not reserved, and has special meaning only in a virtual function declaration) applies to functions not types. The concept of blocking a type from being the source of a derivation chain is not present in C++ (although I can imagine some magic with declaring members `final` to obtain that effect). As of the actual implementation of a `seal`, it is simple: `template <typename T> class seal { friend T; seal() {} };` and then you just need to use CRTP with virtual inheritance on the *final* type.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's just a poor programming. Can't really think of any case where you could actually benefit from such definition.